# Create shipping charge based in produc weight' with Drupal commerce module?

Tags: commerce

I just followed this Randy Fay [video](http://vimeo.com/33838479) which shows how to generate a charge based in the products weight. I works fine. It multiplies the weight of products by a **Cost Per Pound** (CPP)

I need this **CPP** to be different based in the total weight of ALL products in the order.

**Example:**

Order up to 1 pound ........  **CPP** = 0,006

Order with weight higher than 1 pounds ........ **CPP** = 0,004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, create two rules, one where the condition is that the total weight is more than 1 pound and one where the condition is less than or equal 1 pound.

You can setup the rest of the rules to be the same, with only the price (CPP) being different.

Comment: I was trying to do what you say. But I couldn't find the Condition of total weight of the order. But now I found a solution applying this patch for the commerce_physical module which adds that condition: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/node/1721#comment-3315

Comment: @chefnelone You could create a loop in Rules and get it by adding the weight of all the products.

Comment: yes I guess I could, but using the condition provide by the commerce physical is cleaner.